# Optimizing SSAS Performance for Efficient Power BI Loading

Tags: powerbi, ssms, ssas, business-intelligence

I am new to SSAS.
I have a table that has millions of data. I will eventually load it to Power BI. To do that I use SSAS. Until now, I am not able to do full process. It took too long. Too long is not OK for the task I am trying to do. I want to speed the process up.
In order the speed it up, I have some thougths in my mind. Will it be useful to seperate the columns and process it column by column? And combine them later with relations. I am not able to seperate it in source database. I only can do it on the SSAS. And it takes too long to filter data for partition. I wait hours but filtering won't complete. So it looks countereffective. But, do you think that first sorting then filtering speed it?
and do you have additional ideas to speed it up?

Optimizing SSAS Performance for Efficient Power BI Loading

Comment: Your question is too generic. Please update it and provide more details with a specific ask, what you've tried etc... Mention what data source you are using, what process is taking too long, what transformation you looking to achieve. Is Power BI taking to long or SSAS? If SSAS, then remove Power BI tags and reference in the question as it is distracting from the issue.